# Should I remove objects labeled "unknown" from my test set?

Tags: yolo

I'm using an object detector (yolo v5) to detect and identify fish in underwater video.  I have a labeled data set, but some fish are difficult for the annotator to correctly identify, so they get labeled "unknown" instead of with the species name.

My instinct was to train with the "unknown" class included, but to remove it from the test set.  The reasoning being that we are aiming for species identification, and a classifier that identifies "unknown" fish as a species shouldn't be penalized for it.  We are only interested in the accuracy of the labels for the species.

A colleague disagrees, and thinks the training set and test set should have the same distribution.

Thoughts? What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you define the task, i.e. what is the goal of the model:

- In standard classification, an "unknown" category doesn't make sense because there is no homogeneous "unknown" category. It's also risky to include this as a category because if an instance is A but the annotator just doesn't know and labels it "unknown", and if this happens a lot, the classifier will be confused and may predict "unknown" instead of A. Basically this "unknown" class is noise in the data, so normally "unknown" instances are removed not only from the test set *but also from the training set*.
- In some tasks one wants the classifier to be able to predict "unknown", i.e. there is a higher cost of predicting B instead of A than of predicting "unknown" instead of A (for example, a human annotator will review the "unknown" cases but not the others). But this normally requires the "unknown" class to have a special status kind of like "anything else", it cannot be done with regular classification which only predicts the most likely class. For example [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) can be used for this, but it's much more complex.

Comment: The reason for including "unknown" in the data set, is that I am doing object detection - and there is clearly an object there, I just can't be sure what it is.  Maybe a better way would be to have "unknowns" represented as a uniform probability distribution over the (other, real, species) labels?

Comment: @KetilMalde imho in this case your task is closer to open-class classification, the second option that I mentioned. I think it would be a mistake to include this as a regular class. There a are different possible designs: for example you could have a first step which classifies between 'recognizable object' and 'unknown', followed by a second step with regular classes. Another option is to design this task as multi-label classification, if there is no class which obtains a minimum prob then the object is predicted 'unknown'.